# If you reduce the SharePoint version history for a document library, will the oldest versions be deleted?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, versioning, version-history

Example: The default major versioning history for a document library in SharePoint Online is 400 versions.

I am looking to free up space in SharePoint Online.

I want a document library to only retain 100 versions of documents. I also want to delete the oldest 300 versions of the documents.

If I change the major version history for a document library to 100 versions, will the oldest 300 versions be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you change the number of versions that should be retained, and the new number is smaller than the old number of versions, then of course the oldest document versions will be dropped. Anything else would not make much sense, really.

Comment: Ok thanks. And do you know how/when this process will happen? Is it instantaneous? Does SharePoint have something similar to the Managed Folder Assistant (MFA) in Exchange, that runs once a week or so?

Comment: [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/26abd98d-9116-4f98-92eb-2f149e3b1d06/what-happens-to-old-versions-when-the-max-versions-is-reduced?forum=sharepointadminlegacy)  suggests that the old versions will only be removed after the document is opened and saved.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.